# AWS SSH Session getting closed by Server intermittently

Tags: networking, ssh, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, putty

I have connected to the AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance using putty on Windows 7(ppk authentication). Most of the time I'm getting this message on putty: ***Network error: Software caused connection abort***. But this disconnection is happening intermittently.

Putty session have following settings under "Connection":

- Seconds between Keepalives: 5 (Also tried with 30)
- Enable TCP Keepalives: Set to True
  (Checked)

I captured the network packets using Wireshark. It shows that server is sending Connection RESET signal to the client system.

I have 2 putty session connected to same server. Thats why it showing 2 RESET packets.
[image]

Here is the SSH logs (auth.log)

```
May 13 07:38:52 aws-server-1 sshd[30699]: Accepted publickey for dev-user from xx.xx.xx.xx port 49235 ssh2
May 13 07:38:52 aws-server-1 sshd[30699]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user dev-user by (uid=0)
May 13 07:39:01 aws-server-1 sudo:    dev-user : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/dev-user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/tail -f /var/log/syslog
May 13 07:39:01 aws-server-1 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by dev-user(uid=1009)
May 13 07:39:01 aws-server-1 CRON[30961]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 13 07:39:01 aws-server-1 CRON[30961]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
May 13 07:39:43 aws-server-1 sshd[30699]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user dev-user
May 13 07:39:43 aws-server-1 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 13 07:39:44 aws-server-1 sshd[30025]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user dev-user
```

User Sessions:

```
dev-user    pts/0        xx.xx.xx.xx      Wed May 13 07:40   still logged in
dev-user    pts/1        xx.xx.xx.xx      Wed May 13 07:38 - 07:39  (00:00)
dev-user    pts/0        xx.xx.xx.xx      Wed May 13 07:21 - 07:39  (00:18)
dev-user    pts/1        xx.xx.xx.xx      Wed May 13 06:36 - 07:13  (00:36)
dev-user    pts/0        xx.xx.xx.xx      Wed May 13 06:35 - 07:13  (00:37)
dev-user    pts/1        xx.xx.xx.xx      Wed May 13 06:09 - 06:10  (00:00)
dev-user    pts/0        xx.xx.xx.xx      Wed May 13 06:08 - 06:13  (00:04)
dev-user    pts/0        xx.xx.xx.xx      Wed May 13 05:12 - 06:04  (00:52)
dev-user    pts/0        xx.xx.xx.xx      Tue May 12 14:14 - 16:24  (02:10)
dev-user    pts/0        xx.xx.xx.xx      Tue May 12 13:27 - 13:39  (00:11)
dev-user    pts/0        xx.xx.xx.xx      Tue May 12 12:41 - 12:41  (00:00)
dev-user    pts/1        xx.xx.xx.xx      Tue May 12 10:39 - 10:39  (00:00)
```

None of the above sessions are terminated by the user. All sessions are terminated by the server. We haven't changed any SSH settings.

How do I resolve this issue ?

Comment: Are you able to successfully login with username "ubuntu" ?

Comment: I can able to login using ubuntu as well as dev-user. But for both users we are facing this disconnection.

Comment: Ok. I have seen these kind of issues before. Sometimes EC2 instances did not let me login to the server and in that case i had to restore the EBS volume to a new EC2 server and get it work. You can try this approach. this might be the issue with your EC2 instance itself

Comment: Are you actually seeing the SSH keepalive packets flowing both directions while the connection is idle?  n.b., the AWS firewall or *your* firewall is likely to be forging those RST packets with the server's address if your connection is idle and the keepalive aren't happening or are somehow insufficient.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes. I can view both request & ACK packets on Wireshark. In most cases the connections are not disconnecting when its idle. it happened while running some scripts or installation.

Comment: Consider running `tshark` under `screen` on the server.  Although there is not (imho) an obvious cause at this point, I'll bet you capture something that is not consistent with what wireshark sees locally.